# Using accumulate method but can't the first element is always shown as 0

Tags: c++, list, algorithm, iterator

I am trying to write a programm which returns a list whose n-th element is the sum of the first n Values of the transferred list.

```
list<int> summe(list<int> liste) {
        list<int> neueListe;
        list<int>::iterator itr;
        itr = liste.begin();
        int sum = 0; 
        int n = 0;
        
        cout << "Liste mit Summen: " << endl;
        cout << "{ " << endl;
        for (itr = liste.begin(); itr != liste.end(); itr++) {
            sum = accumulate(liste.begin(), itr, 0);
            neueListe.push_back(sum);
            cout << sum << endl;
            n++;
        }
        cout << " }";
        return neueListe;
        
    }
```

```
int main() {

    //Aufgabe 2.2 Teil 2
    list<int> l = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    Algo a;
    a.summe(l);
    

}
```

The output is: 0,1,3,6,10
I think the problem is, that the first loop is accumulate(liste.begin(), liste.begin(), 0); which should be always 0. However I have no idea how to get the first element (although its just one element so theres no need to accumulate).
I want the following output: 1,3,6,10,15.

Comment: You want to accumulate from `list.begin()` to `itr + 1` (prefer `std::next(itr)`). Alternatively, increment `itr` before you call `accumulate` (instead of at the end of the `for` loop - possibly using a `while`).

Comment: Why are you passing `liste` _by value_?  You are copying it for no reason.  Copying a linked list (and then deleting it) is rather expensive with all those memory allocation calls.

Comment: You're re-adding everything from the beginning, for each element.  You could just add the current value to the previous result.

Comment: you could use a ```for``` loop through an ```interger``` index and call ```accumulate``` *method* through each iteration in ```std::List<>```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a wrong algorithm. For this task there already exists the appropriate algorithm `std::partial_sum` declared in the header `<numeric>`.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

std::list<int> summe( const std::list<int> &liste ) 
{
    std::list<int> neueListe;
    
    std::partial_sum( std::begin( liste ), std::end( liste ),
                      std::back_inserter( neueListe ) );
                      
    return neueListe;                     
}   

int main() 
{
    std::list<int> l = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    
    auto l2 = summe( l );
    
    for ( const auto &item : l2 )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 3 6 10 15
```

Or you can transfer the implementation of the algorithm inside your function. For this purpose it is enough to have one loop.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. Is there by any chance a similar method to multiply?

Comment: @Traffix You can use the same algorithm std::partial_sum with a binary operation that represents multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

> The output is: 0,1,3,6,10 I think the problem is, that the first loop is accumulate(liste.begin(), liste.begin(), 0); which should be always 0. However I have no idea how to get the first element (although its just one element so theres no need to accumulate). I want the following output: 1,3,6,10,15.

You've already been shown that this function already exists in `<numeric>` so you don't have to write it.  But I'll answer this specific question anyway so you can learn from it, more generally.

### original fragment

```
        for (itr = liste.begin(); itr != liste.end(); itr++) {
            sum = accumulate(liste.begin(), itr, 0);
            neueListe.push_back(sum);
            cout << sum << endl;
            n++;
        }
```

### rewrite

```
int sum {0};
for (const auto x : liste) {   // use ranged for loop !!!!!
    sum += x;
    neueListe.push_back(sum);
}
```

The various `cout` statements are for helping you understand what's happening, and don't belong in the final code.  Rather, you print the list (or do whatever you need with it) separately.

The value `n` seems to have no purpose, as it's incremented but never referred to anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The `accumulate` method, use as parameters `begin(liste)` iterator and `next(begin(liste), i)`.

```
list<int> summe(list<int> liste) {
    list<int> neueListe;
    list<int>::iterator itr;
    itr = liste.begin();
    int sum = 0; 
    int n = 0;
        
    cout << "Liste mit Summen: " << endl;
    cout << "{ " ;
    for (int i=1; i < liste.size()+1; i++) {
        neueListe.push_back(accumulate(begin(liste), next(begin(liste), i), 0););
        n++;
    }
    cout << " }";
    return neueListe;
}


int mult_op(int x, int y) {return x*y;}

accumulate(begin(liste), next(begin(liste), i), 1, mult_op);
```

out

```
1 2 6 24 120
```